# Broken camera packages

Tags: 18.04, drivers, usb, webcam, camera

Recently, I tried to install gstreamer onto my Ubuntu 18.04 in Lenovo ThinkPad laptop and messed up badly. Now my integrated camera doesn't work anymore. I believe the camera driver packages got corrupted/deleted. Cheese shows "No device found". But the camera hardware is still detected by the system in lsusb and all. It is also showing /dev/video0.

I booted a live image and tested cheese. It was working. So I understood that it is indeed the driver or related issue in the current Ubuntu system. Any help to resolve this is appreciated. Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I am not sure if it's relevant or related, but my ubuntu settings menu also won't open. I have to do gnome-control-center in the terminal every time I want to open it.

Comment: Update: I tried to update my kernel using ukuu. It did not solve the issue too.